# scala mismatch & inferred type arguments with Java

Tags: java, scala

I was tring to use `getDatasID` from `Factory.java` in `test.scala`.

```
//Factory.java
class Factory {
...
    public <K, V, T extends Datas<K, V>> DatasID<T> getDatasID(Class <T> dataClass) ...
}

// C.java
public class C extends Datas<Key, Value> { ... }
```

I used two class in scala to run `getDatasID`

```
//Test.scala
abstract class A[K, V, T[K, V] <: Datas[K, V]]
abstract class B extends Datas[Key, Value]
val targetA = new Factory()
  .getDatasID(
    classOf[A
        [Key, Value, ({type T[K, V]=Datas[Key, Value})#T] 
])

val targetB = new Factory()
  .getDatasID(classOf[B])
```

Both class showed same error.

1. inferred type arguments `[Nothing, Nothing A[Key, Value, [K, V]Datas[Key, Value]]]` do not conform ... `[K,V,T <: Datas[K,V]]`
2. type mismatch

   - found: `class[A[Key, Value, [K,V]Datas[Key, Value]]](classOf[A])`
   - required: `Class[T]`

I would like to match class[Key, Value, Datas[Key, Value]]. The best case will be

```
val targetB = new Factory()
  .getDatasID(classOf[B])
```

Above code works.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Scala can't infer `K` and `V` in this situation, you need to supply them explicitly:

```
new Factory.getDatasId[Key, Value, B](classOf[B])
```

or

```
new Factory.getDatasId[Key, Value, A[Key, Value, _ <: Datas[Key, Value]](classOf[A])
```

(depending on which class you need to pass). If possible, it would be better to change your Java signature, since it doesn't actually use `K` and `V`:

```
public <T extends Datas<?, ?>> DatasID<T> getDatasID(Class <T> dataClass)
```

Comment: Thank you so much!! It was very helpful!

Comment: I just added `class C` in java file at the question. what if I need to `getDatasID` of `class C`?

Comment: @MiaeKim It's exactly the same as `class B`.

Comment: Thank  you! Now I under stand.